Create Dynamic Class Model to get data from ClientSide(Json Formate)
Here is my scenario, I have an API which receives data from multiple resources so I want to create dynamic class based on provided json data and insert that data in sql using entity framework core.
Please suggest your valuable thoughts.
    public Task BindModelAsync(ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        if (bindingContext == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(bindingContext));
        }

        var valueProviderResult = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(bindingContext.ModelName);
        if (valueProviderResult == ValueProviderResult.None)
        {
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }

        try
        {
            var stringValue = valueProviderResult.FirstValue;
            var result = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<ExpandoObject>(stringValue);
            bindingContext.Result = ModelBindingResult.Success(result);
        }
        catch
        {
            bindingContext.ModelState.TryAddModelError(bindingContext.ModelName, "Invalid JSON");
        }
                    
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}

I used this class to get that json data -source(StackOverFlow)

How can you insert it into a database if you don't know the format it is coming in?

When we want to store the data, we shall be ready to use data someday, right? Then which data shall we use? Then we can decide how to design table and column, then we shall know how to create data model and bind to JSON data. Otherwize, recognize the whole json as a string???

Actually you're correct we can't insert the data without knowing the format. But previously We used to write CRUD OP for each table which is problem for us because we have around 2000 tables now I Got a generalized solution for this.  we just  need a table name and the schema but in Json format so that we don't need to use a specific model to receive it. What I did is Just get entity by using table name and serialize the json and then deserialize to Required entity. But now we trying to  build a run time DBcontext so that we can able to reduce the dbset in dbcontext .
